Minimalist load and draw BMP file in Win32?
I'm looking for a minimalist way to load and draw a bitmap in the context of the WIN32 graphics interface. No GDI+, no extra libraries please.
It looks like LoadBitmapA would be the right function to load it, and that will give me a structure of type BITMAP / HBITMAP. But I'm not seeing the corresponding function to draw that object to the screen once loaded. What is it?
I see the Device Independent Bitmap, BITMAPINFO, and its convenient function SetDIBitsToDevice, but how to get BITMAPINFO from BITMAP?  Or is this even the right approach?
(Forgive me, this may be a duplicate, but I see so many answers for so many specialized situations that I don't know which one applies best to me.)

The official Windows imaging API (no GDI/GDI+, no extra library) is WIC ("Windows Imaging Component") for example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wic/-wic-decoder-howto-createusingfilename

GDI+ is Win32 and it's not an extra library. It's always there. The today's way to draw everything is WIC. Going back to LoadBitmap and BITMAPINFO and stuff where nowhere you will find a Windows 98 system to limit you is weird. That said, this question is not useful for SO, but you will get a good answer in ChatGPT.

LoadBitmap() is old, use LoadImage() instead.
You draw an HBITMAP by first SelectObject()'ing it into a source HDC (such as from CreateCompatibleDC()), and then use BitBlt() or other similar function to copy the color data from the source HDC to a target HDC, such as from Get(Window)DC() or BeginPaint().

So how does this all relate to BITMAPINFO (device-independent bitmap) and is there a good way to read BMP  files into that memory format? Or is that a more involved approach?

You don't need a BITMAPINFO to draw an HBITMAP. But, if you want a BITMAPINFO, then 1) for a DIB use GetObject() to get its DIBSECTION and then copy the info to a BITMAPINFO; 2) for a DDB use GetDIBits(), or GetObject() to get a BITMAP and then copy its info into a BITMAPINFO. LoadImage() returns a DIB.
